# openssl ssl_read sends read binary data into char*

Tags: c, binary, openssl, apple-push-notifications

i am trying to write Apple Push Notification Server provider (APNS provider) in c, using openssl.

So far i have been able to succesfuly send a notification via ssl_write, however sometimes it can happen, that the message i sent gets rejected (for whatever reason, bad token, etc...). When that happens and i try to ssl_write, i get -1 bytes written and APNS is then supposed to send back error message and close the connection.

The error comes in as binary and consists of 6 bytes as described in apple documentation here: [Apple Documenatation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)

```
const int written= SSL_write(this->_ssl, buffer, bufferSize);   

int want =SSL_want(this->_ssl);

if(want == 2 ){ //2 means that ssl wants to read 
char bufferRead[6];        
SSL_read(this->_ssl,bufferRead,6);

//Some code that transfers bufferRead into a ASCII format

}
```

I want to ask you, how do i convert this binary bufferRead into something that i can read and store in lets say char* or std::string. The output when converted should look something like this "881234" ...
I appreciate any help i can get.

**EDIT solution by Eran:**

```
   unsigned char command = bufferRead[0]; 
   unsigned char status = bufferRead[1]; 
   unsigned char c2 = bufferRead[2];
   unsigned char c3 = bufferRead[3];
   unsigned char c4 = bufferRead[4];
   unsigned char c5 = bufferRead[5];

int comInt = command;
int statusInt = status;

 int id = (c5 << 24) +
          (c4 << 16) +
          (c3 << 8) +
          (c2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the buffer into 3 parameters.
It has been a while since I programmed in c, but I think you need something like this:

```
char command = bufferRead[0]; // should contain 8
char status  = bufferRead[1]; // the type of the error - the most common being 8 (InvalidToken)
int id = (bufferRead[2] << 24) + 
         (bufferRead[3] << 16) + 
         (bufferRead[4] << 8) + 
         (bufferRead[5]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick answer. I have also tried to parse the buffer with various ways, however it doesn't seem to work. With your solution if i print out command,status,id with std::cout, the 1st two dont print anything and id is 8 numbers (67108864). I am also positive that ssl_read returns int of value 6.

Comment: @Malisak How are you printing the first two? If you are printing the `char` variables, you won't see anything probably because ASCII value 8 is a non printable character. Perhaps you should cast it to int. As for id, what is the value you are expecting? The id should be the id of a message that you previously sent to Apple (you are the one who created that id). In addition, are you sure you are managing to read 6 bytes?

Comment: Ok i have casted 1st two variables into int and it worked, both now print 8 as expected. As for id, i have set previously to 1234 yes. The method for constructing the message format for ssl_write is pretty much the same as in APNS doc previously mentioned. Ssl_read returns 6 as in bytes actually read from the TLS/SSL connection. I tried to do strlen(bufferRead) and it shows 4 ... which is weird.

Comment: @Malisak The number you are getting is 67108864 which equals 1234 * 2^16. This means that when you send the message to Apple you are flipping the order of the high and low 16bits of the ID. You can either fix the code that sends the message to Apple, or change the order of the bytes when reading the id from the response ([4][5][2][3] instead of [2][3][4][5].

Comment: I have tried to swap the order around to the following: `int id = (bufferRead[4] << 24) + (bufferRead[5]) << 16 + (bufferRead[2]) << 8 + (bufferRead[3]);` and the result int id is 0. I am really lost now.

Comment: @Malisak I noticed a mistake in where I put the brackets. Please see updated answer. Perhaps the wrong brackets affected the result. Perhaps you don't have to flip the order (try both orders with the new bracket locations).

Comment: So i tried both cases. With fixxed brackets and reveresed order i get -11772 and with normal order -771489792 (i double checked). I have also tried to cast ever char[2] to char[5] to int to see whats in them  and values are like this (-46 4 0 0). The id i am sending is still 1234.

Comment: @Malisak Based on the values you got (-46 4 0 0), you should try using unsigned char instead of char and then use the following order - [5][4][3][2] - to calculate the ID.

Comment: Alright, that did the trick, order [5][4][3][2] and every char had to be unsigned... int id = (c5 << 24) + (c4 << 16) +  (c3 << 8) +(c2); where c5 to c2 are unsigned chars containing bufferRead[i] I have tested on couple of different ids as well. You sir, have my eternal gratitude. Thank you :)